# Why is the return value of head implicitly converted to Maybe?

Tags: haskell

I've just started to learn Haskell and for practice I've decided to create a function that takes a tree, whose elements have a position and size, and returns the element located at a certain position. My code looks like this:

```
import Data.List (dropWhile)

data Node = Node (Int,Int) (Int,Int) [Node] deriving(Eq, Show)

findNode :: (Int,Int) -> Node -> Maybe Node
findNode loc node@(Node (x, y) (width, height) []) = if loc >= (x, y) && loc <= (x+width, y+height) then Just node else Nothing
findNode loc node@(Node (x, y) (width, height) children) = 
    if loc >= (x, y) && loc <= (x+width, y+height)
        then if not $ null nodes then
            head nodes
        else
            Just node
    else Nothing
    where nodes = dropWhile (==Nothing) $ map (findNode loc) children
```

This code compiles and runs perfectly as far as I can tell, but I'm curious about one thing, Why is `head nodes` acceptable instead of `Just $ head nodes?`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's because your `nodes` has a type of `[Maybe Node]`. You can infact verify that by annotating it explicitly and compiling it again:

```
findNode loc node@(Node (x, y) (width, height) children) = 
  if loc >= (x, y) && loc <= (x+width, y+height)
  then
    if not $ null nodes
    then head nodes
    else Just node
  else Nothing
  where
    nodes = dropWhile (==Nothing) $ map (findNode loc) children :: [Maybe Node]
```

So how does, `nodes` have `[Maybe Node]` type ?

The type of `map (findNode loc) children` is `[Maybe Node]`. (General type of map is `map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]` and in your case the type of `findNode loc` is `Node -> Maybe Node` and hence the resultant type is `[Maybe Node`] ). And the type of `dropWhile` is `(a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]`. In your case `a` already is `Maybe Node` and hence your `nodes` has a type of `[Maybe Node]`.

Comment: @user467526 You might want to `foldr (<¦>) Nothing $ map (findNode loc) children ` to just pick out the first non-Nothing value in the list if there is one, and save yourself the trouble of an if statement and where clause.